# How do I increase the transition time for an onmouseover event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseover

```js
$(function() {
$('details').on('mouseover', function() {
$(this).attr('open', true);
}).on('mouseout', function() {
$(this).attr('open', false);
})
});
```

```css
summary::-webkit-details-marker {
color: #00008B;
font-size: 75%;
margin-right: 2px;
}
summary:focus {
outline-style: none;
}
article > details > summary {
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 16px;
}
details > p {
margin-left: 24px;
}
details details {
margin-left: 36px;
}
details details summary {
font-size: 14px;
}
.wrapper div {
width: 30%;
height: 150px;
float: left;
}
.wrapper:hover div {
width: 16%;
transition: 0.3s;
}
.wrapper div:hover {
width: 40%;
transition: 0.3s;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.div1
{
width: 16.1%;
height: 150px;
padding: 10px;
border: 2px solid blue;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: white;
float:left;
overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="div1" align="left">
<section>
<article>
<details>
<summary><a href="#"><u>General Link</u></a></summary>
<p><b>Some text to be visibile on mousover</b></p>
</details>
</article>
<article>
<details>
<summary><a href="#"><u>General Link</u></a></summary>
<p><b>Some text to be visibile on mousover</b></p>
</details>
</article>
</section>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

I'm using an expanding wrapper. Got the transition delay on that working well.

It's Friday though and my brain is fried and here's what I need help with:

What do I need to add to make the transition time longer on the mouseover and mouseout events for the "General Links" dropdowns? Right now, it's immediate on both.

Here's a pen with the code in action. Everything is working as it should except the transition time on the mouseover and mouseout. That is what I'm hitting a brick wall on.

https://codepen.io/alalien/pen/VwaamLa

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] here instead of including a link to most of the code.

Comment: edited original post and included a new pen.

Comment: maybe you meant the animation of dropdowns?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Added that for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think this achieves the effect you're looking for. The only downside with this animation is that there won't be a delayed fade-out/hide on the element when you mouseout.

```
b {
  animation: visible 1s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes visible {
  from {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
   }
}
```

You could add a transform to slide the text down from the a-tag, but then you will have to play around with absolute positioning and margins on the parent element.

I hope that alleviates your headache. Enjoy your weekend.

Comment: That's definitely going in the direction I saw it. Unfortunately, that CSS doesn't work in the Wordpress corporate set up that's also running under the corporate intranet restrictions. Figuring out what I can get to work and what doesn't can be a real pain.

Is there a way to delay the start of the dropdown animation on mouseover? I got some feedback and that was a repeated question. Testers were stating that running the mouse down to the desired item on the list caused every item above to instantly expand making it confusing. I had to single click to expand, but the higher-ups wanted hover.

Comment: Ah I see. That is unfortunate. I hadn't come across this particular problem before, so I guess you're sick of hearing about animations by now! :D As far as what I have read, there's no way to directly effect the details/summary tags without a CSS workaround.
I found a couple of S/O answers that perhaps you haven't seen already that might trigger a spark for you: 
[one](https://bre.is/J33pDucj), [two](https://bre.is/dGLkXM23), [three](https://bre.is/5M625tHc).
I hope this helps in some way!

Comment: The higher-ups finally saw my point and agreed at the single click to expand is the better option. This was for more reasons than the immediate execution of the onmousover command. Thank you though for researching this for me. I had already looked at the possible solutions you linked and I found several others that I tried as well, but I was never successful in creating a delay. I'm sure the timer function could do it, but my syntax is obviously never correct as the delay never occurs.